# SQL Join in ZF3 Expressive - ResultSet does not give joined Columns

Tags: zend-db, zend-framework3, mezzio

I'm trying to get a title out of a second table (by left-join) but my resultSet isn't delivering the column of the joined table.

This is how my TableGateway looks like:

```
 public function fetchCourseListWithStudyprogram()
{
        $select = $this->getSql()->select();
        $select->where->equalTo('course_active', 'Y');
        $select->join('studyprogram', 'studyprogram.studyprogram_id = course.studyprogram_id', ['studyprogram_title'], $select::JOIN_LEFT);

    $resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);
    var_dump($resultSet);
    return $resultSet->toArray();
}
```

The statement is getting constructed as it should be:

```
public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT `course`.*, `studyprogram`.`studyprogram_title` AS `studyprogram_title` FROM `course` LEFT JOIN `studyprogram` ON `studyprogram`.`studyprogram_id` = `course`.`studyprogram_id` WHERE `course_active` = :where1' (length=214)
```

When it comes to getting results, it ignores the "studyprogram_title" column, I guess its because of the given resultSet (with binded CourseEntity)

Is there any way to show the studyprogram_title without adding it to the CourseEntity? Its not really a part of it so I guess its dirty if I add it there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way how to handle two tables in a model.

If you want to join two tables directly without specifying `tablegateway` for each table then that will raise an issue. That means you can not make the `resultset` to an array because, in this case, you are not using the `resultsetprototype` for the other table as you do for the one (the current model) where you are trying to join two tables.

You may check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583729/7935051)!