# Select with two tables in Zend Framework 2

Tags: sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2, join

i have two tables: user (id, name, email,...) and addi_info(id,user_id,image,...) .
I would like to get all user columns(name,email,..) by having image ( in addi_info table)
Help me please to fix it and thank you.

Comment: Follow this answer please https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583729/7935051

Comment: i would like to get all user columns  by using user_id column in addi_info table !!

Comment: Can you tell me what you are using to connect with your database in Zend Framework? Are you using Zend SQL, or some kind of ORM?

Comment: i'm using zend sql

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you want is something like:

```sql
SELECT user.*, adds_info.image 
FROM user
LEFT JOIN addi_info on addi_info.user_id = user.id
```

If you only want users with an image:

```sql
SELECT user.*, adds_info.image 
FROM user
INNER JOIN addi_info on addi_info.user_id = user.id
```

Note also that it's generally more predictable to select just the columns you want rather than using `user.*`.